# I need to connect to a Progress database with laravel 9 framework, Somebody know how to do it?

Tags: laravel-9, progress-db

I need to connect to a Progress 10.1B database with laravel 9 framework, Somebody know how to do it ?

Comment: It is helpful to know what release of the Progress OpenEdge database you are targeting.

Comment: you are correct i corrected the question

Answer (score 0):

For such an old release of OpenEdge you are probably limited to a SQL connection. The Progress database does support SQL-92 but the DBA may, or may not have configured it. To quickly check use either "ps -ef" (UNIX) or taskmgr (Windows) and look to see if there are any _sqlsrv2 processes running. If there are then SQL connections have been configured and you need to get connection credentials from the DBA. If not you will need to work with the DBA and get SQL connections up and running.